# Concatenation of integers

Tags: number-theory

## Background

**Direct addition** is what some call 'hobo math' (no insult intended); for example, by direct addition, $2+2=22$, and $13+36 = 1336$. I know the process for writing out a number given its digits is something like this (i.e. $1336$):
$$1\cdot10^3+3\cdot10^2+3\cdot10^1+6\cdot10^0,$$
but I wish define a function like this? As in, $DA(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ would return 'hobo addition' of $x_0,x_1,\ldots$

## Question

I believe this might be achievable with some sort of summation, but what sort, I have no idea. I thought something like this, at first:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i\cdot10^i,$$
But: this would only work, to my knowledge, an indexed family of classes. Not only this, but $n$ would have to be obtained by counting the arguments passed to the function, and I have no way of doing this.

*What is the best way I should go about doing this?*

### Edit

I wrote down the wrong formula I was thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a way to calculate the number of digits in the right-hand argument so you can decide how many places to shift the left-hand argument.  The following definition works:
$$
d(n)=\begin{cases}1 & \;{\text{for }}n=0, \\ \lceil \log_{10} (n+1) \rceil & \;{\text{for }}n>0.\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
DA(x,y)=10^{d(y)}x+y,
$$
and for more than two arguments,
$$
DA(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)=DA\left(x_0,DA(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks! This is a perfect answer. Would you mind showing me some examples as to its function? (How to evaluate, that is)?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you're asking, but...presumably you have some way of iterating through the arguments even if you don't know how many there are, so:

```
answer = 0
for each x_i
     answer = answer*10 + x_i
end
```

Comment: Why multiply by only $10$?

Comment: @ErickWong From the problem statement, I supposed that each $x_i$ was a single digit. If it's not, obviously you have to take its log to figure out how long it is (or use some other method).